# does stimulsoft report work on exe file?

Tags: c#, database, connection-string, stimulsoft

I use stimulsoft report for a part of my project in C#. I use Access as database and I use the following connection string to connect to the database.

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database1.accdb;" +
            "Persist Security Info=False";
```

Since I want the code works in other computer, I located the database in the *Debug* folder and use *|DataDirectory|* in "*Data Sorce*".
But whe I use this connection string for StimulSoft I does not work and I have to give the full path of database.

1- Is there anyway to fix this problem?
2- If I give the full path to stimulsoft as connection string and create the .exe file of my project, does it work in other computer?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you locate your database in debug folder, no need to use |DataDirectory|. you should use this ConnectionString:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
```

Usually in WebForm use |DataDirectory|, not in WinApp.